# Create equal number of rows for observations in data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have several hundred data sets that cover several hundred variables for the period from 1875 to 2020. However, there are not the same number of entries for each year, or even none at all, so I would like to adjust the data sets.

Specifically, I would like to have the same number of rows for each year, with the added series for each year containing only NAs. If the year with the most entries has 5 rows in the data set, then all years should have 5 rows in the data set. If a year is not yet included in the data set, it would have to be added with the corresponding number of rows and NAs for all variables.

Due to the size of the data sets I would like to work with data.tables, but I have no idea how to solve this problem in an efficient way using data.table coding. My previous attempts were mainly loop combinations, which made the processing extremely slow. For your orientation, here is a minimal example of the data set structure. Any kind of help is deeply appreciated.

```
First <- 1875; Last <- 2020
Year <- c(1979,1979,1979,1982,1987,1987,1987,1988,1989,1990,1993,1995,1997,1997,1998,1999,2000)
Sums <- c(0.30,1.47,4.05,1.30,1.42,1.86,1.29,0.97,1.54,0.46,0.67,0.98,1.73,0.74,1.70,0.95,0.90)
Days <- c(3,4,3,5,3,3,3,3,7,3,8,10,3,3,3,3,3)

Data <- data.table(Year=Year, Sums=Sums, Days=Days)
```

Ideally, the procedure would output a data.table with a similar pattern. For reasons of readability, the data set does not start with 1875, but 1975.

```
    Year Sums Days
1:  1979 0.30    3 # 1979 has the most observations in the data.table
2:  1979 1.47    4
3:  1979 4.05    3
4:  1982 1.30    5
5:  1982 1.42    3
6:  1982 NA      NA # New observation
7:  1987 1.86    3
8:  1987 1.29    3
9:  1987 0.97    3
10: 1988 1.54    7
11: 1988 NA      NA # New observation
12: 1988 NA      NA # New observation
13: 1989 0.46    3
14: 1989 NA      NA # New observation
15: 1989 NA      NA # New observation
16: 1990 0.67    8
17: 1990 NA      NA # New obeservation
18: 1990 NA      NA # New obeservation
19: 1991 NA      NA # New observation for 1991; year wasn't included previously
20: 1991 NA      NA # New observation for 1991; year wasn't included previously
21: 1991 NA      NA # New observation; year wasn't included 
22: 1992 NA      NA # New observation; year wasn't included 
23: 1992 NA      NA # New observation; year wasn't included 
24: 1992 NA      NA # New observation; year wasn't included 
25: 1993 0.98   10
26: 1993 NA      NA # New observation
27: 1993 NA      NA # New observation
28: 1994 NA      NA # New observation; year wasn't included 
29: 1994 NA      NA # New observation; year wasn't included 
30: 1994 NA      NA # New observation; year wasn't included 
31: 1995 1.73    3
32: 1995 NA      NA # New obeservations
33: 1995 NA      NA # New obeservations
..................
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you also share the expected output for the given example.

Comment: Given an appropriate [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's certainly possible to help you do what you want.  But I am very wary of doing so.  With this much data, I expect you will be summarising your information at some point (average `Sums` by `Year`, for example).  Artificially adding zeroes as you propose *will bias your results* at this point.  You should not do it.  If you need equal numbers of observations in each data frame for other reasons (unlikely, I suspect), using `NA` rather than `0` would be better.

Comment: Your example doesn't work -- the `Year` vector has `,,` in it, perhaps a year is missing?

Comment: Thanks a lot to all! I've included an expected output and fixed the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n <- max(table(Data$Year))
setkey(Data, Year)

Data2 <- Data[J(First:Last), .SD[1:n], by = .EACHI]
```

Or without setting key (thanks to chinsoon12):

```
Data2 <- Data[J(Year = First:Last), on = .NATURAL, .SD[1:n], by = .EACHI]
```

Example output:

```
Data2[Year %between% c(1996L, 1999L)]
#     Year Sums Days
#  1: 1996   NA   NA
#  2: 1996   NA   NA
#  3: 1996   NA   NA
#  4: 1997 1.73    3
#  5: 1997 0.74    3
#  6: 1997   NA   NA
#  7: 1998 1.70    3
#  8: 1998   NA   NA
#  9: 1998   NA   NA
# 10: 1999 0.95    3
# 11: 1999   NA   NA
# 12: 1999   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I ran a few benchmarks with both of your approaches and your original solution was by far the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Another `data.table` option:

```
Data[, ri := rowid(Year)][
    CJ(Year=seq(min(Year), max(Year), by=1L), ri=seq.int(max(ri))), on=.NATURAL]
```

Or for a specific range (`First` to `Last`):

```
Data[, ri := rowid(Year)][
        CJ(Year=First:Last, ri=seq.int(max(ri))), on=.NATURAL]
```

Comment: Never seen `on=.NATURAL` before!

Comment: its item 10 in data.table v1.12.4 (03 Oct 2019) release. https://rdrr.io/github/Rdatatable/data.table/f/NEWS.md

Comment: Thank you @chinsoon12, I haven't heard of `on=.NATURAL` before, but will look it up shortly!

Answer (score 0):

We can find the most number of rows for a particular year using `table` function. We can then use `complete` to include all the incomplete observations from `First` to `Last` year with each year having `n` rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

n <- max(table(Data$Year))

Data %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  complete(Year = First:Last, row = 1:n, fill = list(Sums = 0, Days = 0))

# A tibble: 438 x 4
#    Year   row  Sums  Days
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1875     1     0     0
# 2  1875     2     0     0
# 3  1875     3     0     0
# 4  1876     1     0     0
# 5  1876     2     0     0
# 6  1876     3     0     0
# 7  1877     1     0     0
# 8  1877     2     0     0
# 9  1877     3     0     0
#10  1878     1     0     0
# … with 428 more rows
```